# How can I use Tailwind CSS Classes in the ngClass directive of Angular?

Tags: angular, tailwind-css

I am trying to add dynamic classes to an element in my Angular template based on some condition, and I would like to use the styles provided by tailwind CSS. However, I am not sure how to properly incorporate tailwind into the `ngClass` directive.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

**HTML**

```
<div [ngClass]="getBorderType()">Hello World</div>
```

**TypeScript**

```
getBorderColour(): string {
  const type = {
    Animal,
    Human,
    Doctor,
    Alien
  }[this.type];
  return `border-custom-${type}`;
}
```

Since the class name provided in the run time, the purgeCss have splice the custom classes I have declared in tailwind.config.js.

Obviously, I can make it something like

```
<div [ngClass]="{
    'border-custom-Animal': someCondition,
    'border-custom-Doctor': someCondition,
    'border-custom-Human': someCondition,
    ...
}">Hello World</div>
```

But it is repetitive and harder to maintain. I would like to know if there's an elegant way to handle this?

Comment: You can set the styles in public styles.scss

Comment: You cannot use "dynamic" class names with TailwindCSS, you can look into this [doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names) for details.

Comment: @tromgy you certainly can use dynamic class names as long as you [safelist](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) those classes first. It says this is a last resort but only to keep file sizes low, in this case it would only add a very small number of classes but I certainly wouldn't recommend relying on this heavily.

Comment: Not sure, but the `safeList` is not working whenever I try to add it on the `tailwind.config.js`